# Apple EventHandler error code

Tags: applescript

I used chat GPT to write an apple script for stock data collection from a free polygon API to fill a numbers spreadsheet. When trying to run the script after compiling, the error "An error occurred: Numbers got an error: AppleEvent handler failed" pops up. Everything seems to check out with source path to spreadsheet (not sure if that's correct programming terminology) and I'm not experienced enough to know next steps in troubleshooting this problem.

```
set apiKey to "(I took out the API Key for posting)"

-- Function to make API request and retrieve EPS data
on getEPSData(company, apiKey)
    set apiUrl to "https://api.polygon.io/v2/reference/financials/" & company & "?limit=6&type=EPS&sort=asc&apiKey=" & apiKey
    set apiResponse to do shell script "curl -s '" & apiUrl & "'"
    
    -- Parse JSON response
    set {oldDelimiters, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, linefeed}
    set parsedData to every paragraph of apiResponse
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    
    -- Extract EPS values from parsed response
    set epsData to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of parsedData
        set currentItem to item i of parsedData
        if currentItem contains "\"EPS\":" then
            set epsValue to (paragraph 2 of currentItem) as number
            set end of epsData to epsValue
        end if
    end repeat
    
    return epsData
end getEPSData

-- Main script execution
try
    tell application "Numbers"
        set targetDocument to document "StockEvaluation"
        set targetTable to table "EPS, Historical" of sheet "Sheet 2" of targetDocument
        
        -- Find the symbol column
        set symbolColumn to missing value
        repeat with i from 1 to count of columns of targetTable
            if value of cell 1 of column i of targetTable is "Symbol" then
                set symbolColumn to column i of targetTable
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        
        if symbolColumn is not missing value then
            set dataRows to rows 2 thru -1 of targetTable
            set epsHeaders to {"EPS 2018", "EPS 2019", "EPS 2020", "EPS 2021", "EPS 2022", "EPS 2023"}
            
            -- Add EPS headers to the new column
            set newColumnHeader to make new column at end of columns of targetTable with properties {name:"EPS Data"}
            set value of the first cell of newColumnHeader to epsHeaders
            
            -- Fetch EPS data for each company symbol and add it to the table
            repeat with i from 1 to count of dataRows
                set currentSymbol to value of cell symbolColumn of item i of dataRows
                set epsData to getEPSData(currentSymbol, apiKey)
                
                -- Write EPS data to the new column
                set epsDataRange to cells of newColumnHeader in item i of dataRows
                set value of epsDataRange to epsData
            end repeat
            
            -- Auto-fit the new column width
            set width of newColumnHeader to -1
        else
            display dialog "Symbol column not found."
        end if
    end tell
on error errMsg
    display dialog "An error occurred: " & errMsg
end try
```

Comment: There isn’t enough information to run the script, but getting the data doesn’t look right - parsing JSON is usually more than just getting its paragraphs.

Comment: Run the script under Script Editor, what line generates the error?

Comment: The error appears after I compile and try to run it - A pop up window that says "An error occurred: Numbers got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." It just seems strange because chat GPT wrote it and as such I would assume the code should work?

Comment: Chat GPT just knows how to make text look OK, it doesn’t know anything about programming.  One issue is that the JSON response string is just being split into paragraphs, so there will be an error when trying to get additional paragraphs of a matched item (since there won’t be any).  Actually parsing the JSON string would be the best way to go, but without any sample data it is hard to tell.

Comment: Okay thanks, i'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you're learning to automate and using tools to experiment. If you are going to go with the generative models - you will very much need a good debugger. There are quite a few good posts here on how to debug AppleScript if you get to a shorter script with only one error. To get to that point, you can look at Stack Overflow for the [concept of MCVE which is a critical skill to master](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for any programmer - debugging and reducing and simplifying. It also helps us help you and in turn help others when they have a tricky error or programming issue.